# Feature 'linuxbridge' is experimental

Tags: linux, openstack, openstack-neutron

everyone

When deploying the openstack zed version, I found that the neutron could not be started. I checked the log and found the following error. What is the reason for this?

Error message：
2022-10-20 09:53:46.138 1769211 ERROR neutron.common.experimental [-] Feature 'linuxbridge' is experimental and has to be explicitly enabled in 'cfg.CONF.experimental'

Answer (score 2):

The error seems reasonably clear: you are attempting to use the `linuxbridge` driver in Neutron, and this feature is now considered experimental. You must explicitly enable support for experimental features to use it.

From the docs about [experimental feature support](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest//admin/config-experimental-framework.html):

> Some Neutron features are not supported because the community doesn’t have the resources and/or technical expertise to maintain them anymore. As they arise, the Neutron team designates these features as experimental. Deployers can continue using these features at their own risk, by explicitly enabling them in the experimental section of neutron.conf.

And from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1980948), dated 2022-07-07:

> tl;dr neutron now considers linuxbridge which uses to be the default mech driver in docs to be experimental and it is now guarded by a config flag.

It looks like your options are either (a) enable support for experimental features, or (b) choose a different mechanism driver (e.g, `openvswitch`) .

Comment: How can I enable it? I have added mechanism_drivers_ Drivers=linuxbridge, l2population to the neutron.conf , to enable linuxbridge, but this error still occurs

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in the error message: "...has to be explicitly enabled in 'cfg.CONF.experimental'". See the linked documentation on experimental feature support which includes an example for exactly this situation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know how to solve it